# SDL Web 8 Content Server Installation Issue on Windows 2012 R2

Tags: web8, content-manager

I am getting below Message at the last step of Installation UI window
"Failed to Install product. Failed to install prerequisite 'Windows Features and Roles'. Please try to install prerequisite manually."

Below Listed Windows Features it failed to installed as part of Installation:
[image]

Manuall Installation of these pre-requisite Windows Feature also FAILED in powershell with reason being these are Invalid Feature Names
[image]

Comment: i don't see logs, make sure internet access is there on server to install the prerequisite .

Comment: +1 to Raj's comment. The installer will tell windows to install these pre-requisites, which in turn triggers windows to fetch updates from the Internet. If your server can't access the sites where this is hosted, it won't install them... Alternatively, you can install these yourself, then run the installer.

Comment: Hi Raj,Nuno ;Thanks for sharing comments.The server has internet access and then also its getting failed. For 2nd option to install them manually I tried and found these listed windows features are not part of .Net Framework 4.5 (recommended for SDL web8). Do I need to install .Net Framework 3.5 to fix this issue please suggest

Comment: To add on the above comment, The Failed Pre-requisite Features are not in the list of available windows features on CMS server. List displayed on PowerShell using command : Get-WindowsFeature

Comment: screenshot added for Manual install of Features that FAILED; thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution was to disable/edit the Group Policy that was restricting the script to perform download operation from Microsoft site. The Infra team did that group policy change and after that it worked fine and able to enable the required windows features on the server machine.

Answer (score 1):

I'd check a few things:

1. Check the specific version of Windows Server 2012 R2 you are running? Perhaps you are using a specialized version, like Hyper-V or Essentials?
2. Does the server have free access to the internet. I've seen similar issues when the server requires a proxy to access the internet, and it failed to install .Net 3.5 (dependency of IIS)
3. Use the Powershell command `Get-WindowsFeature` to see if `IIS-ASPNET` is called something else on your machine, for some reason. Not a solution but it might get you to the next step of problem solving
4. If possible, perform a clean install of the OS as see if the problem re-occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try going into the Server Manager > Server Roles and install the Application Server and Web Server (IIS) via the gui. After this is installed, SDL installer should be able to install the rest of the prereqs

Please review the checklist and make sure you fulfill everything here:

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/content.xql?pub=SDL%20Web-v1&lang=en-US&action=topic&xslmode=print&docid=GUID-A6CBE401-9EB7-4534-9362-4B15B19B290E